# Airflow Log file does not exist:

Tags: airflow

Airflow was working fine for several weeks and suddenly started getting errors for a few days.
Dags fail randomly with this error.

> Log file does not exist: airflow_path/1.log
> Fetching from: http://:8793/airflow_path/1.log
> *** Failed to fetch log file from worker. The request to ':///' is missing either an 'http://

Comment: Missing either ... either what (I am guessing https://)

Comment: Hmmm, that `:8793/` looks like a port number to me. So, between  `http://` and `:8793/airflow_path/1.log` you appear to be missing a server name. What changed recently?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me as well using `LocalExecutor` and an Airflow setup on Docker Compose. Eventually, I figured that the webserver would fail to fetch old logs whenever I recreated my Docker containers. Digging deeper, I realized that the webserver was failing to fetch the logs because it didn't have access to the filesystem of the scheduler (where the logs live).

The fix was to ensure that both the `scheduler` and the `webserver` services in `docker-compose.yml` share a volume with the logs, i.e.:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.9"
services:
  scheduler:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - airflow_logs:/airflow/logs
    ...
  webserver:
    image: ...
    volumes:
      - airflow_logs:/airflow/logs
    ...
volumes:
  airflow_logs:
```

Comment: Just a note for Astronomer users – this is already done in the default docker-compose https://github.com/astronomer/astro-cli/blob/main/airflow/include/composeyml.yml 
It's in `if` block checking DuplicateImageVolumes, which is true by default  https://github.com/astronomer/astro-cli/blob/5ef9825731a164e20112762abd1575f89c62bbb5/config/config.go#L77

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I figured that in my case the worker node (I was using Celery Executor) was exhausted and therefore unavailable to execute any dags on it, can you check the CPU and memory utilized by the worker node (or its alternative if you are not using celery executor).

You can try to increase the CPU and memory for that applicable node and try.