# Airflow not creating log files or showing logs in task instance on UI

Tags: python, logging, airflow

Im getting the following airflow issue:

When I run Dags that have mutiple tasks in it, randomly airflow set some of the tasks to failed state, and also doesn't show any logs on the UI. I went to my running worker container and saw that the log files for those failed tasks were also not created.

Going to Celery Flower, I found these logs on failed tasks:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed on host
```

How to solve this?

[image]
My environment is:

- airflow:2.3.1
- Docker compose
- Celery Executor
- Worker, webserver, scheduler and triggerer in different containers
  Docker compose hosted on Ubuntu

I also saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69201032/11949273 answer that might be related.

Anyone with these same issues?

Edit:

On my EC2 Instance I got more vCPU's and fine tuned airflow/celery workers parameters and solved this. Probably is some issue with lack of CPU and or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with some issue. In my case in `Inspect -> Console` has some error with `replaceAll` in old browser (Chrome 83.X). Chrome 98.X does not have this issue.